# LC Filter Creates Ripple Voltage in Buck Converter

Tags: filter, buck, switching-regulator, ripple

I'm currently designing a synchronous buck converter and trying to simulate it in LTSpice. [image]

I know the purpose of L1 and C4 is to act as a filter to smooth out the output, since it would be rapidly switched on and off. However, the LC filter seems to be inducing a very significant ripple voltage, precisely at the resonant frequency of L1 and C4. This is what the output voltage looks like, measured before I1 (it's trying to maintain 24V):
[image]

How would I approach fixing this?

Comment: Try a resistive load, or realistic ESR on L1 and C4 (at their resonant frequency). Alternately, try a current-mode control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of L1 is not principally to be part of a filter, but be the energy storage element that makes the buck converter work. However, it does resonate with C1.

While L1 + C4 *look* like a filter, it's not a proper classical filter design. An LC filter needs at least one of its ports, preferably both, to be resistive. You have the output loaded with a high impedance (current sink), and the input is driven from a near-zero impedance. Neither is significantly resistive, and the result is a nasty resonance.

Things will improve slightly if the actual real load to the circuit has a resistive element to it. Loss in the inductor will also damp the resonance. Obviously though, any series resistance will reduce the efficiency of the circuit.

The normal solution to this problem is to place a snubber at the output, a series combination of R and C, that absorbs energy from the resonance without drawing a DC current or dropping some of the output voltage. The energy that this resistor dissipates has to come from somewhere, and it's from the input, and reduces the overall efficiency, but you did want to tame that resonance, didn't you? This is the least worst way of doing it.

It's probably not worth designing the values analytically when your load is so unrealistic. Model the load and L1's loss better, then play with some RC values in the simulator that you already have set up, to see what they do.